# API Exclude data if date is in the past

Tags: swift

I am trying to exclude data from my API response if the nested list 'calls' contains past properties

Include this data in response:

```
[
   {
      "addressLineOne":"Test",
      "addressLineTwo":"Test2",
      "calls":{
         "dateTime":1597932000, // a date in the future
      },

]
```

Exclude this data:

```
[
   {
      "addressLineOne":"Test",
      "addressLineTwo":"Test2",
      "calls":{
         "dateTime":1596193200 // a date in the past
      },

]
```

I am using JSON decoder to make my api calls:

```
class Service {
    static let shared = Service()
    let BASE_URL = "url.com/JsonData"

    func fetchClient(completion: @escaping ([Client]) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            // handle error
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to fetch data with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let clients = try JSONDecoder().decode([Client].self, from: data)
                completion(clients)


            } catch let error {
                print("Failed to create JSON with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Any direction would be much appreciated

Comment: If you control the backend, it's best do the filtering there (i.e. not return the data that you don't need). Other than that, once you decode, [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) out the array of `clients`.

Comment: You could use the filter function of collections to remove clients with dates in the past. Or maybe the API you’re using supports filtering by adding a parameter to your query. What have you tried?

Comment: Unrelated but never print `error.localizedDescription` in a `JSONDecoder/Encoder` catch block. Print always only the `error` instance to get the **real** error message. Please read also the (accepted )answer to your [previous questiion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63176406/the-data-couldnt-be-read-because-it-isnt-in-the-correct-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by adding a filter and using the built-in `Calendar` function to check the date:

```
class Service {
    static let shared = Service()
    let BASE_URL = "url.com/JsonData"
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    
    func fetchClient(completion: @escaping ([Client]) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: BASE_URL) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            // handle error
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to fetch data with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let myDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                myDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970 // formats date
                let clients = try myDecoder.decode([Client].self, from: data)
                completion(clients.filter { self.calendar.isDateInToday($0.calls.dateTime) // filters dates upon completion
                }) 


            } catch let error {
                print("Failed to create JSON with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

In my solution the API call completes before filtration, which is less-than-ideal as it means all data is downloaded *prior* to filtering, ideally i'd like the data to be filtered prior to download anyone who can point me in the right direction on achieving this is welcomed.

Also this solution only checks if the date is today, not if the date is in the future.