# Swift Decoding: Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead

Tags: arrays, json, swift, decode, codable

I have tried many different ways from many different articles, but I just cannot decode this JSON from a HTTP response.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks.

**JSON:**
This is the JSON returned by Data URL:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "$metadata#GeoFences(Points())",
  "value": [
    {
      "ID": "69d5513c-c1f1-4f5d-aef5-184a913484be",
      "GEOFENCE_NAME": "Dragon Park",
      "GEOFENCE_TYPE": "C",
      "PRIVACY": "X",
      "CENTER_LAT": 32.92536134246622,
      "CENTER_LONG": -117.01864890726854,
      "ZOOM_LAT": 0.007421265080928663,
      "ZOOM_LONG": 0.006358979598971359,
      "PATH_TOLERANCE": 5,
      "ENTRANCE_TOLERANCE": 5,
      "Points": {
        "POINT_TYPE": "E",
        "POINT_NUM": 0,
        "LATITUDE": 32.924186548800414,
        "LONGITUDE": -117.0213193658842,
        "parent_ID": "69d5513c-c1f1-4f5d-aef5-184a913484be"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Structures:**
These are the strifes that I want to decode into. I am hoping for the Value structure with the embedded points structure.

```
struct Value: Decodable {
    let id: String?
    let geofenceName: String?
    let geofenceType: String?
    let privacy: String?
    let centerLat: Double?
    let centerLong: Double?
    let zoomLat: Double?
    let zoomLong: Double?
    let pathTolerance: Double?
    let entranceTolerance: Double?
    let points: GeoFencePointData
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case geofenceName = "GEOFENCE_NAME"
        case geofenceType = "GEOFENCE_TYPE"
        case privacy = "PRIVACY"
        case centerLat = "CENTER_LAT"
        case centerLong = "CENTER_LONG"
        case zoomLat = "ZOOM_LAT"
        case zoomLong = "ZOOM_LONG"
        case pathTolerance = "PATH_TOLERANCE"
        case entranceTolerance = "ENTRANCE_TOLERANCE"
        case points = "Points"
    }
}

struct GeoFencePointData: Codable {
    var pointType: String
    var pointNum: Int
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var parentID: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pointType = "POINT_TYPE"
        case pointNum = "POINT_NUM"
        case latitude = "LATITUDE"
        case longitude = "LONGITUDE"
        case parentID = "parent_ID"
    }
}
```

**Swift Code:**
Seems like this is the typical code used to decode the JSON. I guess main complication is that the response is an array.

```
// Convert HTTP Response Data to a String
if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print("Response data string:\n \(dataString)")
   print("Data: \(data)")
   do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let allGeoFences = try decoder.decode([Value].self, from: data)
        print(allGeoFences)
    } catch {
        print("error: \(error)")
   }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the top-level of your JSON. `struct TopLevel: Codable { let value: [Value]}` and then `let topLevel = try decoder.decode([TopLevel].self, from: data); let allGeoFences = topLevel.value`

Comment: Tip: Do the reverse, transform your struct into JSON, and compare the result. See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63176406/the-data-couldnt-be-read-because-it-isnt-in-the-correct-format/63176830#63176830 Since you wrote `[Value].self`, it means that you'll have a let values: [Value] = [Value(....)]: and convert that into JSON`

Comment: @Larme: I get this error when I try that:
(You are missing the top-level of your JSON.)
error: typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: I copy/paste, sorry, I meant `TopLevel.self`, not `[TopLevel].self`.

Comment: @Larme: When I reverse engineer, can I ignore:
{"@odata.context":"$metadata#GeoFences(Points())","value":?

Thanks

Comment: @Larme: Wow. Thanks so much. It is working as expected. My first post to stackOverflow, and answered so quickly.