# JSON API - Stuck with "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, decode

Generally fairly ok with using decodable etc now but this one is really sticking me. I have an API that returns the following response

```
{
    "data": {
        "contentResults": [{
            "id": 2,
            "title": "news report 1",
            "imageUrl": "www.image.com"
        }, {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "news report 2",
            "imageUrl": "www.image.com"
        }]
    }
}
```

What is tripping me up is the array inside the data object I can't seem to get it to decode properly.

This is my structs for decoding

```
struct TopLevel: Codable { 

    let contentResults: [contentResults]

    

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case contentResults

    }

}



struct contentResults: Codable {

    public var title: String

    public var imageUrl: String

    

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

        case title = "title"

        case imageUrl = "imageUrl"

    }

}
```

Xcode keeps giving me the error "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead" which I do know what it means but I have banged my head against the wall for a few hours now on this one so would like some help. I have referenced this particular page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527849/swift-decoding-expected-to-decode-arrayany-but-found-a-dictionary-instead and whilst it helped me a little it did not get me over the line

Any help appreciated. cheers

Comment: You don't parse the `"data"` level? Are you sure that's the JSON received?  Could you share the code where you decode it? Could you share full error? There are path that could be useful

Comment: Type names begin with an uppercase letter. Make sure you rename your strict contentResults to ContentResults.

Comment: Just the fact that you call a struct TopLevel that isn't the top level of the json is probably the issue. Either decode as [String: TopLevel] and get the value for the key "data" or create a true top level struct

Comment: Joakim can you please explain what the true top level strict would be. I thought I had it :(

Comment: @user2058234 `struct Root { let data: TopLevel }` and decode `Root`. change `let contentResults: [contentResults]` to `let contentResults: [ContentResults]` and change `struct contentResults: Codable {` to `struct ContentResults: Codable {`

Comment: Create a fake `TopLevel` instance "hardcoded", and use JSONEncoder to see what's the JSON it expects. You'll see that you don't have the `"data"` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the part of parsing "data":

```
struct DataResponse: Codable {
let data: TopLevel 
}
```